# Eclipse stuck building

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, workspace

i've changed GIT branch yesterday, and eclipse has been stuck building workspace since. I actually changed to a new workspace this morning,but i still have the same problem. I've imported the maven projects i require, but for the last 30 minutes or so, eclilpse is still building workspace. Other than maven, this workspace does not have any other plugins installed. I cannot perform any work until this completes! Does anybody have any suggestions as to what may be the cause?

Thank you

Comment: mabe "building workspace" is waiting for another operation to finish, do you see any other operations with status "in progress" in the "Progress" view?

Comment: Have you tried running maven via console/terminal?

Comment: there are no other operations in progress window.. i'll try compiling mvn from terminal, good idea.

Comment: maven clean install has compiled all projects successfully. Eclipse still does not want to build!! please help..